# Insert to Oracle using Python ; Tried oracle quote function

Tags: python, oracle

Insert into oracle failed because of single quotes in the data.

Original python code:

```
sql_query = "insert into ptablevalues ({0},'{1}')".format(nextval,row['name'])
```

value of sql_query variable in Python :

```
"insert into pstar values (16655,'O'Hare')"
```

I tried using quote function in Oracle, but still not working

new python code :

```
sql_query = "insert into pstar values ({0},'{1}')".format(nextval,"q\'["+row['name']+"]'"
```

output result

```
"insert into pstar values (16656,'q'[O'Hare']'')
```

What could be the issue

Comment: You should find out how to use proper query parameters instead of trying to glue variables direcly in your SQL statement. https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Please try below removing quotes from '{1}'

```
sql_query = "insert into pstar values ({0},{1})".format(nextval,"q\'["+row['name']+"]'"
```